# How to transfer Mail Server from Apple to CentOS using postfix

Tags: postfix, email-server, centos7

I would like to take the mailboxes from my apple server ("Old Server") and put them on my centOS server ("New Server"), without much if any downtime.

They both have the same MTA: postfix. Now, not sure what Apple Server uses but I think centos 7 also uses Dovecot for storing/retrieving email via IMAP/POP3.

So, would it be possible to 
like mirror the mailboxes in Server A to Server B then kill Server A once Server B is fully backed up?

Looking into this I think I should be able to:

1. Configure Dovecot and postfix on new server as per old server.
2. Copy the Maildir content from old to new server using rsync
3. Start postfix and dovecot on the new/target server.
4. Configure the DNS MX records

Would this be a good general way to go about this?

**Update**

Looking into the subject matter further, I think you can do IMAP -> [Dovecot migration using dsync](https://wiki2.dovecot.org/Migration), which preserves IMAP UIDs and other metadata. This is the recommended way of doing migrations.

Would anyone be familiar with this sort of migration? What are the genral steps to do it this way?

Comment: i think just rsync the pathes and Match the config and it should run if they are the same

Comment: @djdomi Would there not be issues with one server being apple mail the other Centos 7?

Comment: the file Format should be the same* on every System

Comment: if there are only a few mailboxes you could use imapsync. If there are more than 5 it's probably better to use rsync.

Comment: What if AppleMail uses say Cyrus instead of Dovecot?

Comment: @notStan using rsync method. Which files will need syncing over?